# Inner join in persistent or should I use esqueleto?

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I have this fragment describing `Notification` and `Notified` entities:

```
Notification
  type          NotiType
  release       ReleaseId
  date          UTCTime
Notified
  aboutWhat     NotificationId
  unread        Bool
  user          UserId
```

Now I want to write this:

```
-- | Mark specified notification as already seen by specific user. Note that
-- we use 'ReleaseId' to select notification, so this may result in several
-- notifications marked as “read” if they happen to be about the same
-- release. This is generally what you want.

markAsRead
  :: ReleaseId         -- ^ Release in question
  -> UserId            -- ^ User who has seen mentioned release
  -> SqlPersistM ()
markAsRead release user = do
  ns <- selectKeysList [ NotificationRelease ==. release ] []
  updateWhere [ NotifiedAboutWhat <-. ns
              , NotifiedUnread    ==. True
              , NotifiedUser      ==. user ]
              [ NotifiedUnread    =.  False ]
```

This works, but extracting list of notifications as *list* and then using it to select things in another table… well that's not exactly right. Obviously I need a join here and then I will be able to update everything efficiently.

How to do it in pure `persistent`? Is it possible and is it a good idea in this case to stay with `persistent` for this sort of task? Should I use `esqueleto` instead? It looks like I'll need to learn different DSL to work with it, so I'm not sure whether to switch or not.

How to write `markAsRead` properly with `persistent` (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Greg mentioned, Esqueleto is the way to go.  You can try reading [its main module documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.4.1/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html).

Currently Esqueleto doesn't support joins on `UPDATE`s.  However, you can use subqueries to the same effect.

Untested code to get you started:

```hs
-- | Mark specified notification as already seen by specific user. Note that
-- we use 'ReleaseId' to select notification, so this may result in several
-- notifications marked as “read” if they happen to be about the same
-- release. This is generally what you want.
markAsRead
  :: ReleaseId         -- ^ Release in question
  -> UserId            -- ^ User who has seen mentioned release
  -> SqlPersistM ()
markAsRead release user = 
  update $ \n -> do
  set n [ NotifiedUnread =. val False ]
  where_ $
    n ^. NotifiedUnread  ==. val True &&.
    n ^. NotifiedUser    ==. val user &&.
    n ^. NotifiedAboutWhat `in_` 
      (subList_select $
       from $ \t -> do
       where_ $ t ^. NotificationRelease ==. val release
       return $ t ^. NotificationId)
```

Comment: So, this means that I should use Esquelto interface for everything instead of Persistent interface?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use both interfaces at the same time. The only small issue is that there are identifier clashes between, so one of them needs to be qualified.

Comment: Just tried this. It doesn't type-check: couldn't match `Value (Key Notification)` with `ValueList (Key Notification)`. Expected type: `SqlExpr (ValueList (Key Notification))`, actual type `(Value (Key Notification))`. `sub_select` is highlighted.

Comment: Oh, of course, it should have been `subList_select`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your answer and your work on the library. I'll spend some time learning the library's API before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Esqueleto if you want to do joins. Persistent works well with *embedding* data if your DB and your data modelling support that.